Why may CreateFileMapping() throw error 87?
Having looked at this relatively recent example, I adopted its code:
auto hFile = CreateFile(fileName,
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ, // also tried 0 for exclusive
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // 0x108
{
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    std::wcout << "CreateFile " << error << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}

auto hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
    hFile,
    NULL,
    PAGE_READWRITE | SEC_COMMIT | SEC_LARGE_PAGES,
        // also tried PAGE_READONLY
        // also tried without SEC_COMMIT
    0,
    2097152, // Equals to min large page size from Win API
    TEXT("LocalMapping")); // also tried NULL

if (!hMapFile) // NULL
{
    DWORD error = GetLastError(); // ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 87 (0x57) The parameter is incorrect.
    std::wcout << "CreateFileMapping " << error << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}

The application runs under Administrator account.
Other parts of it can successfully allocate large pages of any size from minimum and up, read contents of the same file, and load them into large page buffers.
Comments show what the actual values are. The literal value of 2 MB for the buffer size in this example was obtained from the API call.
Which parameter value are invalid?

CreateFile() passes GENERIC_READ, but CreateFileMapping() then moves ahead to request PAGE_READWRITE access. That seems inconsistent.

GENERIC_READ on the one hand and PAGE_READWRITE on the other hand look weird.

@3CxEZiVlQ In your opinions, which combination of the values should be used instead? Keep in mind that I had originally unsuccessfully tried PAGE_READONLY and only reverted to Microsoft's own PAGE_READWRITE, having gotten error 87.

SEC_COMMIT doesn't work with an hFile parameter. It will do absolutely nothing. SEC_LARGE_PAGES requires SEC_COMMIT but it states in the docs that SEC_LARGE_PAGES is not supported with an hFile. So you need to get rid of creating a file OR get rid of both those flags. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga
Also your file is read-only but the mapping is read-write. Doesn't make sense.

@Brandon Same error without it. Updated the question. The only flag that I cannot forego is SEC_LARGE_PAGES

@Brandon Scratch that! I hadn't tried the specific combination of GENERIC_READ, PAGE_READONLY, and no SEC_COMMIT. That's is the right combination  that works. Now, MapViewOfFile() fails with 87 but it is a different question.

@BusterZo: SEC_LARGE_PAGES "This attribute is not supported for file mapping objects that are backed by executable image files or data files (the hFile parameter is a handle to an executable image or data file)." It means you are still using it wrong. You cannot use this with CreateFile. It also states: "If SEC_LARGE_PAGES is specified, SEC_COMMIT must also be specified.". So if you removed SEC_COMMIT you must remove SEC_LARGE_PAGES. You should be using GetLargePageMinimum as well instead of hard-coding 2097152.

Side note: Look up what that 87 means. Often there are nuggets of wisdom. Not much in this case, but often when you know the name, you can look up what it means with respect to the function being called.

Notice how the Microsoft example you are following is doing: CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, ....); and not using CreateFileMapping(hFile, ....). If you use CreateFile get rid of those two parameters SEC_COMMIT and SEC_LARGE_PAGES. You can already make files as large as you want. Those parameters only apply to PAGE files, not files you manually mapped (data files). Check the docs that I linked.

@user4581301 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes

According to CreateFileMapping,



Value
Meaning




PAGE_READWRITE 0x04
Allows views to be mapped for read-only, copy-on-write, or read/write access. The file handle that the hFile parameter specifies must be created with the GENERIC_READ and GENERIC_WRITE access rights.


SEC_COMMIT 0x8000000
... This attribute has no effect for file mapping objects that are backed by executable image files or data files (the hfile parameter is a handle to a file).


SEC_LARGE_PAGES 0x80000000
... This attribute is not supported for file mapping objects that are backed by executable image files or data files (the hFile parameter is a handle to an executable image or data file).



Finally, the code looks like:
auto hFile = CreateFile(fileName,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ, // also tried 0 for exclusive
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // 0x108
{
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    return NULL;
}

auto hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
    hFile,
    NULL,
    PAGE_READWRITE
    | SEC_COMMIT //no effect
    //| SEC_LARGE_PAGES
    ,
    // also tried PAGE_READONLY
    // also tried without SEC_COMMIT
    0,
    2097152, // Equals to min large page size from Win API
    TEXT("LocalMapping")); // also tried NULL

if (!hMapFile) // NULL
{
    DWORD error = GetLastError(); // ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 87 (0x57) The parameter is incorrect.
    return NULL;
}


Is t hat going to map to a large pages buffer? If not, then this does not answer the question.

@BusterZo As SEC_LARGE_PAGES says, Enables large pages to be used for file mapping objects that are backed by the operating system paging file (the hfile parameter is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE). For Using Large Pages, see Creating a File Mapping Using Large Pages.

That's the link in my original question. Your answer does not address the issue.

What's your problem? Why may CreateFileMapping() throw error 87?

Your answer shows how to create a mapping backed by regular pages. I need large pages. The link that you provided does not work.
